# Implementing try-catch block with throw statements

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

In a guessing game I have to make, I need to include a try-catch block with two catch clauses (one multi catch block for my two custom exceptions: `BadGuessException` and `TooManyGuessesException`, and one block for `NumberFormatException`).

I tried creating conditions in my program to throw my custom exceptions, because I don't know the logic behind how else they would work properly. I am having compilation errors, and would like help re-working my program so that it implements the try-catch-catch block properly.

My custom exception classes:

```
public class BadGuessException extends Exception
{
  /**
   * no-arg constructor
   */
  public BadGuessException()
  {
    super("Sorry, that was an invalid guess!");
  }

  /**
   * parametrized constructor
   * @param message String message passed to super class's constructor
   */
  public BadGuessException(String message)
  {
    super(message);
  }
}

public class TooManyGuessesException extends Exception
{
  /**
   * no-arg constructor
   */
  public TooManyGuessesException()
  {
    super("Sorry, too many guesses!");
  }

  /**
   * parametrized constructor
   * @param guess integer value representing amount of guesses (turns)
   */
  public TooManyGuessesException(int guess)
  {
    super("Sorry, you guessed " + guess + " times!");
  }

}
```

My program, which is having compilation errors:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame throws NumberFormatException
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Scanner object to receive user input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Create Random class object & random variable
    Random rng = new Random();
    int n = rng.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;

    //Initialize incrementor for guessing turns
    int turn = 1;

    //Create variable for user input (guess)
    int guess;

    try
    {
      while(guess != n)
      {
        //Exception handling for more than five turns
        if(turn > 5)
          throw new TooManyGuessesException();

        //Prompt user to enter their guess
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10 inclusive.");
        System.out.println("Hint: the answer is " + n);
        //Receive user input (their guess)
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Increment turn variable
        turn++;

        if(guess < 1 || guess > 10)
          throw new BadGuessException();
        else if(guess == n)
          System.out.println("YOU WIN!\nIt took you " + turn + " attempts.");
      }
    }
    catch(BadGuessException e | TooManyGuessesException e)
    {
      e.getMessage();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Sorry, you entered an invalid number format.");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What compilation errors do you get? Don't make us guess.

Comment: `Error: Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead`, among other compilation errors that look like syntax errors due to errors in my code structure (that I don't know specifically).

Answer (score 1):

Make the changes in the GuessingGame  class Remove **e after BadGuessException** in multiple try block. and initialize guess with 0 and remove the NumberformatException from your class declartion;

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Scanner object to receive user input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Create Random class object & random variable
    Random rng = new Random();
    int n = rng.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;

    //Initialize incrementor for guessing turns
    int turn = 1;

    //Create variable for user input (guess)
    int guess = 0 ;

    try
    {
      while(guess != n)
      {
        //Exception handling for more than five turns
        if(turn > 5)
          throw new TooManyGuessesException();

        //Prompt user to enter their guess
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10 inclusive.");
        System.out.println("Hint: the answer is " + n);
        //Receive user input (their guess)
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Increment turn variable
        turn++;

        if(guess < 1 || guess > 10)
          throw new BadGuessException();
        else if(guess == n)
          System.out.println("YOU WIN!\nIt took you " + turn + " attempts.");
      }
    }
    catch(BadGuessException | TooManyGuessesException e)
    {
      e.getMessage();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Sorry, you entered an invalid number format.");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: To preface, I also removed my `throws` statement in the header. When I tried this, I got: `Error: Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7`

Comment: Which JDK version of java you are using and how are you compiling your code

Comment: I'm compiling on DrJava and I think I'm using JDK10

Comment: You are using JDK below version 1.7, Multiple try-catch functionality was introduced in JDK 1.7

Comment: Check your JDK version by going to Edit > Preferences > Compiler Options and clicking the No Preference Combo Box